# Why was Rocky's verse of "Rose Tint My World" replaced?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show

As most *Rocky Horror* fans are aware, the actor who played Rocky (Peter Hinwood) couldn't sing, so he would lip-sync his lines in songs, and the vocals were recorded by Trevor White.

However, there are two different versions of Rocky's verse from the song *Rose Tint My World* (the first song of the Floor Show sequence):

- original theatrical release version:

- later version (note - the video should begin at the start of Rocky's verse, but if you play the whole video, you may see a wardrobe malfunction from Little Nell/Columbia;  this is presumably NSFW):

### Why was the original version of this verse replaced with the new version in some editions of the movie?

Comment: Couldn't sing. Couldn't dance. Couldn't act. His struggle was real.

Comment: "I'm just seven hours old-" "AND CAN'T DANCE!"

Comment: Couldn't even read lines, apparently.

Comment: I dunno and google is being unhelpful in the extreme :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two bits of [IMDb's trivia page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073629/trivia) seem to cover the explanation of why the lyrics changed from one version to another:

> Peter Hinwood couldn't sing well. During the soundtrack sessions a session singer was used for Rocky Horror's part. Hinwood mimed the vocals during filming. In post-production, Jim Sharman wanted to change Rocky Horror's voice, and hired Australian actor/singer Trevor White to dub the final vocals for the film. White was interviewed for the 2002 book "Rocky Horror: From Concept to Cult."

And:

> The film was originally recorded in mono. When 20th Century-Fox finally decided to release it to home video in 1990, the songs in the film were re-dubbed using the stereo versions from the soundtrack release (a session singer was used in the studio version for Rocky's vocals; Trevor White re-dubbed them for the film). Rocky's vocals are different on "Rose Tint My World," and other subtle differences are noticeable to fans who have seen the theatrical release repeatedly, especially because the words didn't match to the mouths of the actors. The original English mono sound was used as an option for the 2000 DVD release (with Trevor White as the voice of Rocky Horror on all songs), along with an English 5.1 Surround mix (using the mono sound and White's vocals) and a commentary track by Richard O'Brien and Patricia Quinn.